# calculating $\mathrm{Var} (e^{-X})$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

suppose $X$ has probability density function $f_\theta(x)=\exp(-(x-\theta)-\exp(-(x-\theta)))$. how can I calculate $\mathrm{Var} (e^{-X})$

Comment: Show your work, and explain where and why you're stuck.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the change of variable formula, in order to obtain the density function of $Z = e^{-X}$? $Z$ has a very well known distribution.

Comment: +1 @Alecos : I'd have done $Z=\exp(-(X-\theta))$ myself (dealing with the factor of $\exp(\theta)$ in the Var() being simple enough), but it only differs by a multiplicative constant from your approach so it's not really different in any substantive way.

Comment: @Alecos you might consider writing a version of your hint as an answer (for self-study questions, hints and guidance are okay as answers).

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for the variance of a function of a random variable $Z = h(X) = e^{-X}$. The function $h()$ is continuous and monotonic in $X$, so the change-of-variable formula, to obtain the density function of $Z$ can be applied without special issues (see for example [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)).

But then, we will have to perform a whole lot of additional calculations of integrals, to obtain the first and second raw moments of $Z$, in order to arrive at the variance... well in this case we won't, because once we obtain the density function of $Z$, we will realize that it is the density of a *very* well-known distribution, and so the expression of its variance is common knowledge.